# SAS Create conditional duplicate rows - repeating rows for an instance and assigning weight to the duplicate rows

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I need to transform my data to input into a model. I am doing this with sas. Below is the original format of the data and two options of what the model will accept. Option 2 is ideal. Is there a way to do this in SAS? I keep trying to come up with data steps but end up in circles.

## *ORIGINAL DATA FORMAT*

| ID | Total | Risk |
| --- | --- | --- |
| recordA | 3 | 3 |
| recordB | 5 | 2 |

## **OPTION #1:**

| ID | Target |
| --- | --- |
| recordA | 1 |
| recordA | 1 |
| recordA | 1 |
| recordB | 1 |
| recordB | 1 |
| recordB | 0 |
| recordB | 0 |
| recordB | 0 |

## **OPTION #2:**

| ID | Target | Weight |
| --- | --- | --- |
| recordA | 1 | 3 |
| recordB | 1 | 2 |
| recordB | 0 | 3 |

I tried subtracting columns and making a flag for whether Risk>0 then Target 1 else 0 but run into issues creating repeated records

Comment: Why are there 2 obs for B and 1 for A in option 2?

Comment: 1 instance of record B where risk (my target) =1 and 3 where it isn't. Total =3 risk + 2 not risk or in otherwords, Total = 3 counts of recordB as Target =1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with a data step with two `output` statements. `weight` is always equal to `risk` when `target = 1`, and we always want to have an output row for that. If `total` does not equal `weight`, then we need to create a second output row where `target = 0`. In that case, weight is `total - risk`.

```
data want;
    set have;
    
    target = 1;
    weight = risk;
    output;

    if(total NE risk) then do;
        target = 0;
        weight = total - risk;
        output;
    end;

    keep id target weight;
run;
```

Output:

```
id        target   weight
recordA   1        3
recordB   1        2
recordB   0        3
```

Comment: That worked! Thank you! man I feel like a dummy. For some reason I couldn't wrap my head around adding the records.